# Limit Google Maps V3 to 1 marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I had code that was working for map V2 but have since upgraded to V3 and the constructors are different.  I want to limit my map to 1 marker only.  Here's the code to add a marker:

```
myListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
```

....

```
 function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location, 
      map: map,
      draggable: true
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
```

I need code that will remove myListener once a marker is placed.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

try *google.maps.event.addListenerOnce()* method instead

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it did the trick:

```
    myListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng), google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);

  });
```